# Application server hosting

Tags: qt, server, hosting

I'm writing a Qt/C++ application and i plan to add a network part with socket connection to a server implemented in Qt also.

If i host locally the server there is no real problem.

But if i want to share my application (client part) with some people and then be sure my server is always running, the best way would be to have a distant server.

Could you give me some clue to do it ? It's not still clear for me for steps to follow in this case.

- Is it a better way for that ?
- Can i find free hosting ?

Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I have answered the question for You to get the idea, however I'm not 100% sure this question should be on SO as it seems as a small off-topic/too broad to be answered properly.

Comment: The question is not related to Qt itself but to how to host it etc. as answered.

Answer (score 5):

There are generally 3 options:

**1. Local hosting**

This is server running at Your physical location. You can set it clearly as You want and the server will do whatever You want. But must be turned on the whole time, when there is no other work it will just consume power. Also You must get all the hardware (server components), software for running (Operation system), network device and connection (some router, which needs to have special set-up [NAT, port-forward, ...], speed and reachability of the internet connection) and most likely also some security device/SW (firewalls or so).

This is best idea for basic developement and testing. But once the service should work for public audience, it is not really worth to run server Yourself.

---

**2. Remote hosting (virtualized or dedicated server)**

This option was the top in last 20-30 years, where all the `Web developers` and `App developers` were putting their software on some prepared server. Dedicated is physical server running at some providers' location, who are lending You the hardware (and maybe some license for OS/other SW). Virtualized machine is just 1 hardware piece (server) with multiple virtual servers on it (more clients running on same hardware).

This got generally benefits as the networking/security/hardware issues are being carried out by the `hosting owner`. You are just borrowing some diskspace and computer time/performance. Normally the company will provide whole server, on which You can set up several services, run multiple protocols, etc..

Ideal solution for webs and single/few (not much) instances of server application(s).

---

**3. Cloud hosting**

This is the newest technology at the moment (alive around 10-15 years [eg. AWS running since 2006, Azure since 2010]). Datacenter owners (from 2. point) get better and created some applications on the servers, which will do all the work for You (mostly automatically). In few clicks the servers are running and application can be deployed, used database engines, web pages, IOT hubs, ... **quite lot of stuff**. Benefits are clearly that You just have to spent minimum of time to set up things and they will run. With high uptime (eg.: 99.9995%).

Difference between dedicated & cloud: On dedicated server there can be put almost any OS which fits the needs, run just services You want, have full control. In cloud solution, You don't have so much of "physical" control and the data moreless live somewhere in Datacenters all over the world. But generally it is more scalable solution and once Your app will be used by lot of users from public sector, this is best way to go.

---

**Common ideology:**

The most common solution is that when You develop, You create local server on which You deploy, test, improve. Once stable, order a server either on cloud or as dedicated/virtual machine and deploy it there. Some developers knows that their App will run on cloud services from the very beggining so they order it and start developing against it, but in most cases there is no need for that.